# Timescaledb - How to display chunks of a hypertable in a specific schema

Tags: postgresql, chunks, timescaledb

I have a table named `conditions` on a schema named `test`. I created a `hypertable` and inserted hundreds of rows.

When I run select `show_chunks()`, it works and displays chunks but I cannot use the table name as parameter as suggested in the manual. This does not work:

```
SELECT show_chunks("test"."conditions");
```

How can I fix this?

Ps: I want to query the chunk itself by its name? How can I do this?

Comment: `show_chunks` accepts the table name as a string, not as an identifier, see https://docs.timescale.com/v1.3/api#show_chunks
Have you tried to provide schema name within the string?

Comment: A chunk is a table, thus it can be queried by normal PostgreSQL query, if you have enough permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show_chunks` expects a regclass, which depending on your current search path means you need to schema qualify the table.

The following should work:

```sql
SELECT public.show_chunks('test.conditions');
```

The double quotes are only necessary if your table is a `delimited identifier`, for example if your tablename contains a space, you would need to add the double quotes for the identifier. You will still need to wrap it in single quotes though:

```sql
SELECT public.show_chunks('test."equipment conditions"');
SELECT public.show_chunks('"test schema"."equipment conditions"');
```

For more information about identifier quoting:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Edit: Addressing the PS:

> I want to query the chunk itself by its name? How can I do this?

```sql
feike=# SELECT public.show_chunks('test.conditions');
                show_chunks                 
--------------------------------------------
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_28_1176_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_28_1177_chunk
[...]

SELECT * FROM _timescaledb_internal._hyper_28_1176_chunk;
```